# Connect two 64x32 RGB P4 panels Arduino Mega

Tags: arduino-mega, rgb-led

I'm using an Arduino Mega and two RGB Led Panels to plot some data. The problem is that the data plotted in the first panel is duplicated in the second as well. What I want is to plot the data on both using just one Arduino Mega. Is it possible? I've read that you can achieve it using one Mega for each panel or using a more powerful controller for both. This question was asked before here

[Join two rgb ledPanel 32x64 in order to get one 64x64 (How to)](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/67431/join-two-rgb-ledpanel-32x64-in-order-to-get-one-64x64-how-to)

but no clear answer about commands or changes to made in the code were given. Any idea?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not sure how to handle this, because you're basically describing your own question as a duplicate.  So, it seems like anyone attempting to answer it shouldn't answer on the existing question.  If you're around here long enough, not very long, to get a few reputation points you'd be able to set a bounty on the existing question.

Comment: I voted up and made some minor edits to the linked question. There's a small chance it may receive some attention being further up the list. I also looked in the RGB Matrix library they reference and about the only I have to say about it thus far is a warning, that it will allocate 32*64*3, over 6 KByte for one matrix.  Since the Mega 2560 has 8Kbyte, it doesn't appear that trying to make two instances of it will fly.